# Can bower automatically write <script> tags into index.html?

Tags: yeoman, bower

I'm using yeoman's backbone generator, and I ran this:

```
bower install backbone.localStorage -S
```

And I manually had to insert this into index.html:

```
<script src="bower_components/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage.js"></script>
```

Is there some way for bower to automatically insert `<script>` tags? I thought part of the benefit of bower was not having to figure out in which order to include your scripts?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just run

```
grunt bowerInstall
```

after bower install

Comment: Hm, strange, I just did `bower install socket.io` and then `grunt bower-install` and my grunt serve output shows `>> File "app/index.html" changed.

... Reload app/index.html ...
Completed in 0.000s at Wed Mar 19 2014 14:08:13 GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...` and yet I don't see a change in my app/index.html file. How?

Comment: `grunt bower-install` produced an error for me.  I had to use `grunt bowerInstall`.

Comment: Yes, the name was changed on Feb 10, 2014 (https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install/commit/e0481a097e5f3ed47c9612b80be3d0af1cecdfc1), updated my answer

Comment: Interesting the command that works for me is `grunt bower-install` grunt `v0.4.5`

Comment: It can be automaticly done by live reload ;-) `watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  }`

Comment: here is the ref in case you need:  https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-bower-install

Answer (score 16):

You can use [wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/wiredep) to push dependencies into your HTML code from bower. This is the approach [used by generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/master/app/index.js#L286) when you run `yo angular`:

```
var wiredep = require('wiredep');
wiredep({
   directory: 'app/bower_components',
   bowerJson: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./bower.json')),
   ignorePath: 'app/',
   htmlFile: 'app/index.html',
   cssPattern: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}">'
});
```

Comment: Nice spot! Here is the link to wiredep docs https://github.com/stephenplusplus/wiredep

Comment: I am doing this after installing Bootflat but no scripts or css are added to my index.html

Answer (score 8):

Bower won't add support for a specific function like this, but will soon allow you to specify an action to take after 'bower install'ing a new package. This will be called a "postinstall," similar to npm.

In the meantime, however, I have created a library to help with this. Since you're using yeoman, just add "grunt-bower-install" as an npm 'devDependency', then follow the instructions here: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install.

Comment: Note that `grunt-bower-install` has been renamed `grunt-wiredep`: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep

Answer (score 4):

Use --save

```
bower install --save <YOUR_PACKAGE>
```

> The --save option updates the bower.json file with dependencies. This will save you from having to manually add it to bower.json yourself. **You'll see that the script section at the bottom of index.html has automatically updated.**

Reference: http://yeoman.io/codelab/install-packages.html

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go. It works the same as `npm  --save` option adds it to package.json.

Comment: -1. You are correct that this updates the bower.json, but this is not what updates the index.html.  Notice that the tutorial asks you to run `grunt serve` before checking the index.html file.  `grunt serve` calls `wiredep`, and that's the magic for injecting the dependencies.

Comment: I used this for adding the angular-jqcloud package, and it made script entries for jqcloud in my index.html, automatically.